# Creating a csv-file from an srt-file ("Friends" subtitles) in python

Tags: python, csv, srt

Currently, I am trying to create a csv file containing the subtitles of NBC's "Friends" and their corresponding starting time. So basically I am trying to turn an srt-file into a csv-file in python.

For those of you that are unfamiliar with srt-files, they look like this:

```
1
00:00:47,881 --> 00:00:49,757
[CAR HORNS HONKING]

2
00:00:49,966 --> 00:00:52,760
There's nothing to tell.
It's just some guy I work with.

3
00:00:52,969 --> 00:00:55,137
Come on.
You're going out with a guy.

…
```

Now I have used `readlines()` to turn it into a list like this:

```
['\ufeff1\n', '00:00:47,881 --> 00:00:49,757\n', '[CAR HORNS HONKING]\n',
'\n', '2\n', '00:00:49,966 --> 00:00:52,760\n',
"There's nothing to tell.\n", "It's just some guy I work with.\n",
'\n', '3\n', '00:00:52,969 --> 00:00:55,137\n', 'Come on.\n',
"You're going out with a guy.\n", ...]
```

Is there a way to create a dict or dataframe from this list (or the file it is based on) that contains the starting time (end time is not needed) and the lines that belong to it. I've been struggling because while sometimes just one line corresponds to a starting time, other times there are two (There are two lines at most per starting time in this file. However, a solution that can be used in case even more lines are present would be preferable).

Lines that look like the first one ("[CAR HORNS HONKING]") or others that simply say e. g. "CHANDLER:" and their starting times would ideally not be included but that's not all that important right now.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: The first character in your result is the Unicode BOM. There must be some mistake in your current code, because normally that would silently disappear.

Comment: I just used 

`with open(filepath) as f:

    text = f.readlines()

    print(text)`

It is the only strange entry in the output list, so I guess it's not that important for my issue, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this code cover your problem. The main idea is to use a regular expression to locate the starting time of each legend and extract its value and the corresponding lines. The code is not in the most polished form, but I think the main idea is well expressed. I hope it helps.

```
import re

with open('sub.srt', 'r') as h:
    sub = h.readlines()

re_pattern = r'[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3} -->'
regex = re.compile(re_pattern)
# Get start times
start_times = list(filter(regex.search, sub))
start_times = [time.split(' ')[0] for time in start_times]
# Get lines
lines = [[]]
for sentence in sub:
    if re.match(re_pattern, sentence):
        lines[-1].pop()
        lines.append([])
    else:
        lines[-1].append(sentence)
lines = lines[1:]         

# Merge results
subs = {start_time:line for start_time,line in zip(start_times, lines)}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly!

Comment: I am glad to know it. Good luck with your project Kaiser.